# SSL error on youtube and google

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, youtube

This is everything it says. I honestly have no idea what the heck is going on. This just started happening a couple days ago. This is everything it says.

> Cannot connect to the real www.youtube.com
>
> Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to
>   www.youtube.com.
>
> Try to reload this page in a few minutes or after switching to a new
>   network. If you have recently connected to a new Wi-Fi network, finish
>   logging in before reloading.
>
> If you were to visit www.youtube.com right now, you might share
>   private information with an attacker. To protect your privacy, Chrome
>   will not load the page until it can establish a secure connection to
>   the real www.youtube.com.
>
> Reload  Less What does this mean?
>
> www.youtube.com normally uses encryption (SSL) to protect your
>   information. When Chrome tried to connect to www.youtube.com this
>   time, www.youtube.com returned unusual and incorrect credentials.
>   Either an attacker is trying to pretend to be www.youtube.com, or a
>   Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information
>   is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data
>   was exchanged.
>
> Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will
>   probably work later. You can also try switching to another network.

Technical details

```
www.youtube.com has asked Chrome to block any certificates with errors, but the certificate that Chrome received during this connection attempt has an error.
Error type: HSTS failure
Subject: *.suddenlink.net
Issuer: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
Public key hashes: sha1/onEq6kt0EoB17E9a33RAQpceLX4= sha256/JDQTMzVwG8Qmk3G7uqLOeSU6xHMsrbtcpgyIoddroaI= sha1/lfnXQ0sc5x3vQhHua+PA4CVvrZU= sha256/emrYgpjLplsXa6OnqyXuj5BgQDPaapisB5WfVm+jrFQ= sha1/gzF+YoVCU9bXeDGQ7JGQVumRueM= sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=
```

Comment: 1. Is your clock is synchronized with internet time? 2.Did you have any tool bars installed? 3.Is this happening with all the browsers?

Comment: Yes my clock is synchronized. I have Adblock, Adblock for Youtube, Hangouts, Privacy Palette, and Unfollowers for Chrome. Yes this is happening on all my browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody is inferring with your SSL connection. This might be:

- Doing SSL interception for security reasons. This is often done in companies.
- You are behind some capture portal, which intercepts connections for unauthorized users to ask them to login or accept the side policy or similar things.
- Somebody is trying a man-in-the-middle attack. This might also be adware or malware on your own system.

> HSTS failure Subject: `*.suddenlink.net`

Suddenlink is a cable provider. If this is your ISP than maybe they ask you to authorize somehow , e.g. a capture portal. Try to go directly to their page to find out or use a http-only (no https) target so that their capturing works without errors.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you got infected with some sort of browser hijacker
I suggest you to download and scan your pc with [malware bytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same SSL/HSTS problem on all computers and phones connected to WiFi today. after checking the computer date and resetting the modem and router, I contacted Suddenlink and found out we had exceeded the monthly usage allowance of 250G.  We started using Chromecast a little over a month ago, so I'm betting that's the issue.  The CSR gave me this link:
https://activate.suddenlink.net/activate/self-service
which in turn gave me an error code message and a number to call.  I asked the CSR why only SSL traffic was affected and they did not know other than to say that's just the way Suddenlink decided to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and it's resolved by changing certificate setting in group policy settings (GPEDIT.MSC). See the image for settings:

[image]

computer configuration > windows settings > security settings > public key policies